# BBPress bbp_new_reply action not firing when user replies to embedded thread

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I'm working an educational website that produces video content and uses a BBPress forum for discussion rather than the native WordPress comments. Here's how it works:

I have a hook on `wp_insert_post` that creates a new BBPress `topic` when a new `video` post is created and saves this new `topic_id` to a `_comment_topic_id` meta field.

In my `single-video.php` template where the video is displayed, I'm using the BBPress `[bbp-single-topic id=$topic_id]` shortcode to display the topic thread and reply form for people to post comments.

All of this works great! I'm just having one problem - the "subscribe" feature of BBPress isn't working when people post replies via the Video Single page. The reply is posted just fine, but subscribed users don't receive a notification. If you're not familiar - when a user subscribes to a thread, they receive an email whenever someone replies to the thread. This is still working fine when someone posts a reply via the actual Thread single page - it's only a problem on the thread embedded via the shortcode on the Video single page.

I've tried digging into the core and I got so far as to discover that the `bbp_new_reply` action isn't firing - BBPress uses a function called `bbp_notify_topic_subscribers` hooked into `bbp_new_reply` to send the notifications and that function isn't running at all when a reply is made via the Video single page.

It seems that BBPress uses some hidden inputs to determine what actions to run after a reply has been submitted, but those seem to be included properly through the shortcode. These appear at the bottom of the Topic single form (that works properly);

```
<input type="hidden" name="bbp_topic_id" id="bbp_topic_id" value="422573">
<input type="hidden" name="bbp_reply_to" id="bbp_reply_to" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="bbp_post_action" value="bbp-new-reply">
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="83ea236cd1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/forums/topic/SLUG/">
```

And these appear at the bottom of the Video single form (that doesn't)

```
<input type="hidden" name="bbp_topic_id" id="bbp_topic_id" value="422573">
<input type="hidden" name="bbp_reply_to" id="bbp_reply_to" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="bbp_post_action" value="bbp-new-reply">
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="83ea236cd1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/videos/SLUG/">
```

I'm at a loss for how to debug this issue further and could really use some help. BBPress has all kinds of page type/post type checks in the core that I've been ducking and weaving around, but this one has got me stumped. I suspect the problem is that SOMEWHERE it's checking the post type of the current post, seeing it's a `video` instead of a `topic` and bailing before the action runs, but I have no idea how or where to find that and how to patch around it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I have a similar problem. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041576/functions-of-bbpress-in-other-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out every lead I was following was a red herring.

I had another function hooked into `wp_insert_post` that was redirecting you back to the Video single page instead of sending you to the Thread single page if you posted your reply FROM the Video single page. It turns out that redirect was hitting and stopping execution before the `bbp_new_reply` actions were allowed allowed to fire.

I changed that function to also hook into `bbp_new_reply` and changed its priority to 11 so it would run after the native actions. Working great!